# Extracting average cell values of multiple buffer zones in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, buffer, arcgis-10.5

I am trying to find a tool capable of extracting the average values of multiple buffers zones that I created around some GPS coordinates.

I have a layer in ArcMap that shows temperature in a field, I also have created a 12-ft buffer zone around some random locations (inside that field). I am aware that in order to extract multiple values in ArcMap, I can use the "Extract Multi Values to Points" (Spatial Analyst)tool; however, what I need is to extract the average values inside my multiple buffer zones.

Does anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this using ArcMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to extract the average values of buffer zones, the "Zonal Statistics" tool can be used.

[image]